# What do I do after integrating Google Pay API?

Tags: java, android, google-pay

I have successfully intergrated the Google Pay API into my android app, and i am confused where to go from here. I understand i need to fill out this form "https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlepayAPIenable/" but I am having some difficulties I don't understand what is payment processor or how to go about implementing this? Could someone assist me? I have already researched it and read the developers documentation but i still do not understand. For my app I would simply like to allow user's to donate to charities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [integration checklist](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/integration-checklist) that shows complete list of steps if you haven't already done so.

After that, it is a matter of completing the [form that you referenced](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlepayAPIenable/) in your question.

> I am having some difficulties I don't understand what is payment processor or how to go about implementing this?

Google Pay doesn't process the payment. It provides a way for users to securely share payment credentials with the developer and/or a payment processor.

There are two types of integration that is available with Google Pay:

1. [Payment Gateway](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#gateway)
2. [Direct Integration](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#direct)

The general advice is to us a [supported payment processor](https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors) as the gateway because they manage their own PCI DCSS compliance obligations. I suggest first selecting a payment processor if you haven't already got one and take it from there.

For `DIRECT` integration, refer to one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59033500/google-pay-api-integration-in-android/59145808#59145808) for more information.

Comment: How I can get money after implementing google pay, is in google pay account or in the payment processor?