# Google Pay does not show total price or displayItems

Tags: android, google-pay

I was trying to integrate Google Pay to a native Android app. I read the doc and played around with the sample project and I noticed that there is no total price displayed on the popup for Google Pay. (There is email, shipping address, card info though) I also tried in my app and it is the same. In my code, I also added `displayItems` and they are not shown either. Sorry no code is attached here. But all I wonder is whether it is normal for the Google Pay popup not to show total price or display items on the Android app, or is it because I didn't do it correctly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 6):

You didn't miss something, I faced the same problem and contacted google pay support, they said

> To display final amount at Google Pay payment sheet is only available
>   for website. For now this is not available for Android Integration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a fix for this is being rolled out soon. Unfortunately I don't have an estimated time of arrival for the fix.

If you get in contact with the Google Pay support team they may be able to get this fix out to you sooner.

https://pay.google.com/business/console/ > Contact Support

Answer (score 0):

Displayitems only show on website and only if you use **Authorize Payments** or **Dynamic Price Updates**.

The official demo indicate this:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos
The official dev doc also address this:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects

Just for the total price is a bit tricky. I use Braintree to integrate with Google Pay, and I find only the following currencies (among the [135 currencies](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/general/currencies) that Braintree support) can show the order total:
BGN, EUR, CHF, CZK, DKK, HRK, HUF, ISK, NOK, PLN, RON, SEK
Seems they are all in European area, not sure is it related to some regional financial requirement.