# Can we implement google pay api for our android app in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-pay

Implemented google pay api into my android app using https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial and https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart

The default country code is **US** and currency code is **USD**. My issue is that I need to use the app in Saudi-Arabia, but I cannot change the Country/Currency code. If I change it (**country code: SA and currency code: SAR**) an error occurs with **Error code: 412.**

Also, changing parameter **billingAddressRequired** to **false** is of no use as address is still mandatory for payment.

So,

1. Can I implement google pay api for my android app in Saudi-Arabia and how to do so?
2. Can I hide billing Address in the payment page and how to do so?
3. Can I display **total amount** in the google pay payment pop-up along with the card-details and all?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: WRT 3. See my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61392809/12031739

Answer (score 1):

Google Pay is supported in Saudi Arabia. Refer to [list of supported countries](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/9023773?hl=en).

What parameters are you passing in?

It is working for me using the web integration with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lyh6b543/). Should requests should be similar between Android and Web.

```js
// transactionInfo
{
  displayItems: [
    {
      label: "Subtotal",
      type: "SUBTOTAL",
      price: "11.00",
    },
    {
      label: "Tax",
      type: "TAX",
      price: "1.00",
    }
  ],
  countryCode: "SA",
  currencyCode: "SAR",
  totalPriceStatus: "FINAL",
  totalPrice: "12.00",
  totalPriceLabel: "Total"
}
```

You can refer to the [Google Pay live demos](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos) for more examples of parameters that you can pass in.

Comment: Total amount not showing in android popup. Thanks in advance